# select distinct and other column in the same row

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an easy, non-JOIN way, to perform this task?

```
mysql_query("select DISTINCT artist, id from ringtones where artletter='A'");
```

Result should be: all artist values without duplicates with corresponding id.

Comment: What are you getting? And what do you expect to get?

Comment: is there any join in this query ???

Comment: provide more information, table structure would help. What exactly should  be selected?

Comment: Have you tried using 'GROUP BY artist'? This will eliminate all duplicates...but also only give you the first ID it finds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get one row per artist, with all the IDs for that artist on one line by doing this:

```
SELECT artist, GROUP_CONCAT(id) as `IDs`
FROM ringtones
WHERE artletter='A'
GROUP BY artist;
```

If you want only the *first* `id`  for each artist, try this:

```
SELECT artist, MIN(id) as `first_id`
FROM ringtones
WHERE artletter='A'
GROUP BY artist;
```

(you could get the *last* `id` by using `MAX` instead of `MIN`)

If you want the first or last *row* (based on `id`) for that artist, you can do a [groupwise max](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) as described in that link.

Comment: the first one shoulb be what u need

Comment: Second one is exactly what I need. Thanks Jeremy =)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this..

```
select DISTINCT artist, id where id IN(select DISTINCT id from ringtones where artletter='A')
```